# DataTable Select method

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a list of rows in my datatable.
Now I wish to prioritize the rows not according to `DESC` or `ASC` but based on few similarities of my variables with the row values.

For example,
I have datatable with columns as below:

```
Name, Location, Age, Sex, Education..
```

And I already have some preferences of seeing those rows first which match my education and location, and those rows which doesn't match, can be after the first row.

How do I accomplish this?
I tried setting expression in `SELECT statement` with `OR` and `LIKE clause` but I didn't seem to be getting the right answer.

> ```
> DataRow[]  row = ds.Tables[0].Select("Affiliations LIKE '%" + ftr2 + "%'OR Loc_city LIKE '%" + city1 + "%'OR Edu_Hist LIKE '%" + ftr + "%'OR Work_Hist LIKE '%" + ftr1 + "%' OR Priority='true'");
> ```

here i dont want to be strict that i want these values only but a preference setting that i want these values first, rest can be behind it..

Comment: then u have to get the matching column and use order by matching_column name desc

Comment: can you give example of table data values and the expected result?

Comment: @Prabhavith - yeah but i am not strict with match only. means want others columns too.. how do i do that?

Comment: @Tani You have to get the columns dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Can you have upload some code samples you have already tried ?

try like this

```
DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Orders"];
// Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date.
string expression;
expression = "Date > #1/1/00#";
DataRow[] foundRows;

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = table.Select(expression);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: You have to add a space between "%'OR in your code, try that first

Comment: As i said i dont want `ASC` or `DESC` but selecting keywords i want to see first

Comment: hmm ok i'll do that..and let you know

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Union select statement, first select the matched rows and than the unmatched
like this:

```
   string selectQuery="select Affiliations LIKE '%" + ftr2 +
                       "%'OR Loc_city LIKE '%" + city1 + 
                       "%'OR Edu_Hist LIKE '%" + ftr + 
                       "%'OR Work_Hist LIKE '%" + ftr1 + 
                       "%' OR Priority='true' 
                           union select Affiliations not LIKE '%" + ftr2 + 
                       "%'and Loc_city not LIKE '%" + city1 + 
                       "%'and Edu_Hist not LIKE '%" + ftr + 
                       "%'and Work_Hist not LIKE '%" + ftr1 + 
                       "%' and Priority !='true'"
```